# How to compress images with Google App Engine Blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

We have an app that servers a series of images from blobstore.  An
example is here:

http://lh4.ggpht.com/f76xUkRZLRkb_Qz5uu82TX3LoBRh4eYb9hxYwMRMLCk5ghO_OL0DW2v4rRnkewUyDWfBuBttgbUvuJJXwtFQosEB=s0

It was a huge png, so this downloads at 536K.

If we resize it to 400 across, it's still huge (263k):

http://lh4.ggpht.com/f76xUkRZLRkb_Qz5uu82TX3LoBRh4eYb9hxYwMRMLCk5ghO_OL0DW2v4rRnkewUyDWfBuBttgbUvuJJXwtFQosEB=s400

How can we request or store the picture in some kind of better
compression?  We have a mobile client for our app, and waiting through
273K is making it really slow.

Answer (score 10):

There is [Images API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/). To compress and resize image:

```
// get image from blobstore
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
Image oldImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromBlob(blobKey); 

// compress & resize it
OutputSettings settings = new OutputSettings(ImagesService.OutputEncoding.JPEG);
settings.setQuality(90);
Transform transform = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(newWidth, newHeight) 
Image newImage = imagesService.applyTransform(transform, oldImage, settings);
byte[] blobData = newImage.getImageData();

//save data to blobstore
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("image/jpeg", someFilename);
FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, true);
writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(blobData));
writeChannel.closeFinally();

// get the blobKey to newly written data
BlobKey blobKey = fileService.getBlobKey(file);
```

Comment: May I know how I do the same in python?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: There is also Images API for Python: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [Pagespeed service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#pagespeed) to re-compress images on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PIL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27) to serve the re-compressed image dynamically from your frontend instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload differents version (with different compression ratio) of your images to the [blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) or [cloud storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/) and select the version to display client side (using CSS or client side logic).