# How to save a rotated image which was stored in GAE Blobstore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to rotate and save an image which was already stored in blobstore. For this I tried using [`images.Image.rotate` method](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/#Python_Transforming_images_from_the_Blobstore)

```
img = images.Image(blob_key=image.blob)
img.rotate(180)
final_image = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.PNG)
```

I don't know how to save the rotated image again to the blobstore.

Comment: I didn't yet use GCS yet, so I'm not 100% sure, but I'd try the method in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019626/how-to-upload-image-to-the-cloud-storage-via-app-engine

Comment: @DanCornilescu we are currently using blobstore not GCS,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transformed `image` is just a collection of bytes that you can write back to the Cloud Storage - as a new object or overwrite an existing one (e.g. `cloudstorage.open` with mode set to "w" using Python GS Client).

Comment: My answer is the same - a transformed image is bytes. Save them to the Blobstore, if you prefer, although I would recommend moving to GCS.

Comment: ya, I managed to store the converted image using your method. BUt it's still in binary/octet form. I'm struggling to convert it to jpeg. My BLobstore viewer fails to show the image inline because it's not in jpeg format. But if I download and view it in an image viewer, it seems fantastic (img_in_rotated_form).,

Comment: Of course - it's a blob. You will need to set the correct headers, including "Content-Type", when returning this blob to a browser. You can also set a file name and tell the browser whether to render or save the file using "Content-Disposition" header.

Comment: got that http://stackoverflow.com/a/34653324/3297613 . But donno how to set the filename..

Answer (score 1):

Writing to the blobstore used to be possible using the [Files API, which is now deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore).

You can use GCS instead for writing the image ([GCS is recommended over Blobstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753840/if-youre-storing-an-image-blob-in-app-engine-should-you-put-it-in-the-blobstor?rq=1) anyways).

You can still keep [the blobstore API with GCS](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage) if you want. I *think* it should be possible to even mix blobstore and GCS transparently for your users so that you don't have to migrate all your existing images from the blobstore to GCS.

Comment: `I think it should be possible to even mix blobstore and GCS` really?

Comment: is there any way to do like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13731894/3297613 in python?

Comment: That was the Files API (note the answer is 3 yrs old).