# How to set the content type of an image before storing it to blobstore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to rotate and save the image to GCS with the below code.

```
img = images.Image(blob_key=image.blob)
img.rotate(270)
t = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.PNG)
filename = '/' + UploadHandler.get_gs_bucket_for_images() + 'blobstore_demo.png'

with gcs.open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(t)

blobstore_filename = '/gs' + filename

key = blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)
```

But when I try to view the file using GAE's blostore Viewer, I get an encoded image. That is, the content-type for that blob is not set to `image/png`. So how I managed to set the content-type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your image mimetype, just edit yor code this way:

```
img = images.Image(blob_key=image.blob)
img.rotate(270)
t = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.PNG)
filename = '/' + UploadHandler.get_gs_bucket_for_images() + 'blobstore_demo.png'
mimetype = 'image/png'
with gcs.open(filename,'w', content_type=mimetype) as f:
    f.write(t)

blobstore_filename = '/gs' + filename
```

key = blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)

Comment: How i failed to see the contents of `gcs.open` method?

Comment: it displays `filename` as `None`.. Any sol for this?